/etc/fstab suddenly empty – why?
I have a Raspberry Pi 5 with 8 GB memory that boots from an M.2 (NVME) drive. OS is the latest Raspberry Pi OS.
I installed xrpc
and connected to the Raspi from another Linux box through Remmina RDP – worked fine.
Then I connected from a Windows box with its native RDP; that terminated the first RDP session, but worked fine as well. Now I selected "Shutdown" from the Raspberry menu in that RDP session – nothing happened here, but the monitor that was directly connected to the Raspberry now showed a login box on a white background.
I rebooted the box from an ssh window, but instead into the "Fisherman" screen, the Raspi booted always into that login screen.
I could terminate that login screen through CTRL+ALT+F2 and then I could login with pi on the console. On checking the logs I found that several files could not be written because the respective filesystems were read-only.
mount revealed that in fact the filesystem mounted on / was read-only – what surprises me! So I want to have a look into /etc/fstab – the file was there, but with a size of 0 bytes …
I booted from an SD card and created a new /etc/fstab; with that, the Raspi booted again without problems and showed the "Fisherman" … all works fine again!
Now my question: any idea what could have emptied that /etc/fstab? And more important: any idea how can I prevent it from happening again?

same for me, strange
